# How to pass the user id along with JWT tokens in local storage

Tags: laravel, authentication, vue.js, jwt, local-storage

I am currently working with **Laravel** and **Vue** framework and I am using **JWT auth** for authentication. The problem is that I want to pass the `user_id` along with token to *local storage*, so that if I need to use it somewhere I can get access to it easily by `window.localstorage.getItem('user_id')`. I am unable to do so. I am new to these technologies, Please help

I have tried passing the token and it was a success, but for some reason I am unable to pass the id.

my JWT auth code is:

```php
public function login(Request $request)
{

    $credentials = $request->json()->all();

    try{
        if (!$token = JWTAuth::attempt($credentials)){
            return response()->json(['error'=>'invalid_credentials'], 400);
        }
    }catch(JWTException $e) {
        return response()->json(['error' => 'could_not_create_token'], 500); // something went wrong whilst attempting to encode the token
    }

    return response()->json(compact('token'));

}


public function getAuthenticatedUser()
{
    try{
        if(!$user = JWTAuth::parseToken()->authenticate()){
            return response()->json(['user_not_found'], 404);
        }
    }catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenExpiredException $e){
        return response()->json(['token_expired'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\TokenInvalidException $e){
        return response()->json(['token_invalid'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }catch(Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException $e){
        return response()->json(['token_absent'], $e->getStatusCode());
    }

    return $user;
    // \Log::info('user id found'.$userId);

}
```

I want to store the id when the user gets registered and logged in and it stays in the local storage for use and is only deleted when the user gets logged out of the current account.

Advance Thanks.

Comment: You can make a new webservice for getting user details  by passing generated token. Use this code:
try {
            $this->jsondata = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);
            $this->message = 'User details fetched.';
         $this->status = true;
        } catch (JWTException $e) {
         $this->status = false;
         $this->message = 'Error';
        }

        return response()->json([
  'status'  => $this->status,
      'data'   => $this->jsondata,
      'message'  => $this->message
        ]);

Comment: @azm_shah thanks for reply..but can you tell me where I have to put this code

Answer (score 3):

Make a new function in your controller below login function.

```
public function user_details(Request $request){

    try {
        $this->jsondata = JWTAuth::authenticate($request->token);
        $this->message = 'User details fetched.';
        $this->status = true;
    } catch (JWTException $e) {
        $this->status = false;
        $this->message = 'Error';
    }

    return response()->json([
        'status'    => $this->status,
        'data'      => $this->jsondata,
        'message'   => $this->message
    ]);
}
```

Don't save user_id in browser's local storage as it will be a major security issue. Use this webservice to get any user's details via generated token.

Comment: where I have to look for details.. I have to console or it will store the details in localStorage

Comment: Are you using Jwt for rest API?

Comment: I think you should store token in localStorage rather than storing other info

Comment: @AJ yes, I am using Jwt for rest API...I am storing token in localStorage but I am unable to get user id my vue component, that is why i wanted to pass the id

Comment: @AstaLavista Yes now you can use a post request, pass this stored token and get response from user_details webservice.

Comment: Could you please elaborate on why storing the user_id in localStorage is a major security issue? I mean, the big thing is that it cannot be revoked and is valid indefinitely, but otherwise it seems not much different than storing the JWT